# Is "as long as" grammatically correct?

Tags: expressions, sentence

I would like to know whether following sentence is correct:
*The battery does not last for as long as it says on the label*

Comment: Yes it is, as Pitarou and Barrie have pointed out. Though your first sentence should have a definite article before _following,_ i.e, _whether **the** following sentence is correct._
_The following X_ is an idiom, and requires _the_.

Comment: People do sometimes use *for **so** long as it says* - possibly because, like you, they're not sure it's okay to repeat "as" in this way (their concerns are unfounded, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

It offends no rule of English grammar.

Answer (score 3):

It’s fine. You can delete the word “for” if you want to.